# move a div from one li to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to sort from two li. If i will delete any div it will be sort by asc.

[The fiddle is](http://jsbin.com/batedepi/1/edit)

i am using jquery append to to move div.
please take a look in my delete function

```
function del_slide(no,sdiv)
    {       
        $('.s'+no).remove();    
        
        
        if(sdiv==1)
        {
            alert("first");
            $($('.bxslider .btm-slides').last()).appendTo(".bs1");
            
        }
        else if($('.bxslider .btm-slides').last())
        {
            alert("last");
            $($('.bxslider .btm-slides').last()).appendTo(".bs1");
        }
    
    }
```

If i am deleting any item !. Then divs are not in order.
How to do all the items in ascending order? I can't do this sort. Please help me.

I need to put first li full. If i will delete any div from first li then one of 2nd li's div should move to the first div. If i will delete from last li the div will be on the same position.

If i will delete any div then last li will blank. But first li will contain 3 div.If I will delete a div from first li then one div from second li will come to first one.

Comment: Finally what's your question..?

Comment: After deleting it is not is ascending order

Comment: My sorting is not working.Please help me.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy have you got my problem..

Comment: Sorry i will change it later..

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie ,please cool down you are making Question asker nervous!

Comment: @PratikJoshi i can't describe the question clearly.

Comment: Hey @TrueBlueAussie someone just already modified the question.

Comment: i have to put 3 div in every li. after deleting of div every li will contain 3 div. If there is less the 3x div then last li will be blank.

Comment: I am currently rewriting the whole thing to make sense to me, so every clue helps... when you delete an item, do you just want the deleted blanks at the end of that section (li) and move the other items up?

Comment: yes. If i will delete any div then last li will blank. But first li will contain 3 div.If I will delete a div from first li then one div from second li will come to first one.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie i think now question is little bit clear..

Comment: If you use `$('.s'+no).html('');` instead of `$('.s'+no).remove();` it will not change the order after remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you want something that works like this?

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/H6PY6/3/

I removed all the unnecessary classes and links and inline javascript as you can connect it all with jQuery and work out the positions via jQuery DOM traversing.

```
$(function () {
    $(".bxslider").on('click', '.editText', function (e) {
        // Stop click of link
        event.preventDefault();
        // Edit code goes here

    }).on('click', '.delSlide', function (e) {
        // Stop click of link
        event.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        // Find current slide we clicked
        var $slide = $this.closest('.btm-slides');
        // Get parent of slide
        var $parent = $slide.closest(".bottom-slides");
        // if parent li is the first li
        if ($parent.closest('li').index() == 0)
        {
            // Move up one slide from the last li
            var $from = $parent.closest(".bxslider").children().last();
            // Move up one item from second section
            $parent.append($from.find('.btm-slides:first'));
        }
        // Empty the contents of the deleted slide
        $slide.html('');
    });
});
```